# Interacting with Ethereum smart contract that has been deployed via address

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I'am total beginner in Ethereum so how to interact with smart contract via address ? here is the address : 0x259a065256212183490b3ee3f4702c900c37d712

ABI:

[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"}]

Or did I miss something ?

Comment: what did you try? how did you develop the smart contract? what is the network?

Comment: I didn't do nothing I need to call the getAddress function to get the address of the event

Comment: In order to find out, you'll have to do some interaction with the Ethereum smart contract that has been deployed at this address: 0x259a065256212183490b3ee3f4702c900c37d712

Simply call the contract's getAddress() function and the location will be revealed to you :)

Oh, you might find contract's ABI useful as well:

[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"}] 


But I don't now really nothing about what to do this is my first day with Ethereum

Comment: start with remix IDE at http://remix.ethereum.org , follow a basic tutorial. that will give you a basic idea

Answer (score 1):

Use delegatecall(), this low level version should return exceptions as well.

```
function callfunction(address _atAddress) payable public {
    address _impl = _atAddress;
    require(_impl != address(0));

    assembly {
      let ptr := mload(0x40)
      calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize)
      let result := delegatecall(gas, _impl, ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
      let size := returndatasize
      returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

      switch result
      case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
      default { return(ptr, size) }
    }
  }
}
```